# flutter card elevation ruined when having very long list

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

flutter card elevation ruined when having very long list.
its normal on top of the list but getting weird for the bottom list.

```
FutureBuilder<List<CalData>>(
        future: fetchNews(),
        builder: (context, snapshot) {
          if (snapshot.hasData) {
            List<CalData> posts = snapshot.data;
            return new Column(
                children: posts
                    .map((post) => Card(
                      elevation: 1,
                        child: Container(
                            padding: EdgeInsets.all(10),
                            child: Row(
```

[image]